# How to create custom search page in SharePoint 2010 with free-forms and drop down search selections?

Tags: search

The search page required is a single page form with multiple free-form and drop down search selections. How to go about creating custom search page in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Build a custom web part in Visual Studio that performs a search, you can have as many controls as you want. This would require an understanding of building custom web parts, which can't be imparted in a forum such as this.

If you have a programming background in VB.NET or C#, you should be able to pick up the differences. You can google "Building Custom Web Parts in SharePoint 2010", here is a fairly decent one I found:

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I would go for the web part solution as well. You can easily pass your search query to the result page by adding it in the query string of the result page URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Search you have 2 Options

1. [Keyword Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556426%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. [SharePoint Search SQL Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If you are using FAST search then you can use [FAST Query Language (FQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394606%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check this post may it help you to customize the advanced search out of the box web part

http://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/add-custom-search-properties-in-your-advanced-search-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Please  provide more details, link-only answers have a tendency if becoming very little when the link breaks. As I understand it, this link is to your private blog? If so, it is even more important for you to show that you are interested in this community and not only to drive traffic to your blog :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are correct answers.  There are many solutions to this problem.  I would also suggest using the SharePoint Search Application's asmx web services, with the community-standard jQuery library SPServices to call ws.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Search

This is will result in a light-weight sandbox-able ajax search web part.